# How to prevent VueJs to update data earlier than DOM completely mounts itself

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```vue
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            channels: channelz.Root.Channels.Channel,
            currentIndex: 1,
            columnNumber: 9,
            rowNumber: 7,
            windows: {
                width: 0,
                height: 0
            }
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
        window.innerWidth < 1200 ? this.handleResize() : console.log("Window size hasn't changed!");
    },
    destroyed() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    },
    methods: {
        handleResize() {
            this.windows.width = window.innerWidth;
            this.windows.height = window.innerHeight;
            this.checkAndChangeColumnRow();
            //this.checkRowNumber();
        },
        checkAndChangeColumnRow() {
            var calcCol = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i < this.channels.length; i++) {
                calcCol++;
                if (this.$refs[i][0]['y'] != this.$refs[i + 1][0]['y']) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.columnNumber = this.columnNumber !== calcCol ? calcCol : this.columnNumber;
            this.rowNumber = (this.channels.length - 1) % this.columnNumber == 0 ? parseInt((this.channels.length - 1) / this.columnNumber) : parseInt(this.channels.length / this.columnNumber) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to manipulate and find column and row number of the items in the flexbox. I am trying to find it out by the properties of this.$refs properties as you can see in the code above. Unfortunately, checkAndChangeColumnRow function updates it earlier than items gets completely rendered.

Edit: Resolved the issue by adding an event listener in mounted. It calls the same function twice in a row and it somewhat gives the correct output in the second callback.

```
 mounted() {
     window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
     window.addEventListener('load',this.checkAndChangeColumnRow);
     window.innerWidth < 1200 ? (console.log("Width çok azmış yaa"),this.handleResize()) : console.log("Window size hasn't changed!");
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    window.removeEventListener('load',(this.checkAndChangeColumnRow,console.log("Event has been detached.")));
  },
```

Comment: *it updates it to bizarre numbers* what updates what to "bizarre numbers"? what is a "bizarre number"?

Comment: For instance, it was supposed to update the column number to 15 and row number to 4 but it updates them to 25 and 3 and it ruins the flow of the program.

Comment: why 15 and 4? please explain why you think some condition would produce those values - perhaps your maths is wrong

Comment: It has someting to do with the calling the function in undesired time. I think function works too early than expected. How can I fix that?

Comment: the function is called when the component is mounted - what makes you think that is "too early" - I still think your calculation is probably wrong, but you've still given no indication why it should be 15 and 4 when it is 25 and 3 - what conditions (besides `window.innerWidth < 1200`)  would result in 15 and 4? i.e. it has something to do with `this.channels` and `this.$refs[i][0]['y']` but it's not clear why

Comment: I have now updated my code and it gives me the desired output. I will show it in few minutes. Problem has probably caused b lifecycle hooks.